# Instagram banned my server ip address to use __a=1 api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have a little application which needs to retrieve some public pages info by calling instagram.com/[username]/__a=1 .

my application was working for about a week and suddenly instagram changed its way and instead of retrieving JSON data, it just redirected me to login page.

I can run my app in local... so I thought my server IP is banned or marked somehow.
I have used multiple proxies but it seems those IP addresses were banned too.

finally I used a valid sessionid and my application is working properly.

is instagram going to ban my account ?
if it is, how should I get public pages ?
I have read about depreciation of instagram api and new instagram graph api, and it appears to me that old api which have capability of satisfying my need, is going to be disabled in 2020, and new api platform is only for Business and Creator accounts. am I wrong ?
if I am right, what should I do then?

Comment: The Basic Display API might be your best bet, but right now app review is closed due to covid-19. Thanks for the sessionid tip, it got my program up and running while I migrate to an official API.

Comment: does Basic Display API help me for getting public pages media_urls and profile_url ?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced exactly the same. Right now I managed to circumvent this issue by letting my applications users be the ones who request the JSON data (through a $.getJSON jquery request), as opposed to my server being the one doing the request. Since every user has a unique IP address, instragram lets all their requests go through. I then take the data their request receives and forward it to my server.

Right now, probably due to extensive testing, Instagram even blocked my home IP address, so when I'm on my home WiFi I cannot access the instagram JSON feed but when I switch to my phones 5G internet, I am able to do JSON requests for public profiles.

It is sad that Instagram has to block requests to public profiles this way, but I guess if you don't make too many requests from the same source or use dynamic IP-addresses you should be fine!